# plot the circumference of a circle using ParametricPlot2D

Tags: plotting

I use the following command

```
Subscript[ϵ, e] = 0.0;
Subscript[R, 0] = 15;
f[θ_, ϕ_] := 
  1 + (4 Subscript[ϵ, e])/(1 - 
       3 Subscript[ϵ, e]) (Cos[θ]^4 + 
      Sin[θ]^4 (1 - 2 Sin[ϕ]^4 Cos[ϕ]^2));
x = Subscript[R, 
    0] (f[θ, ϕ] Sin[θ] Cos[ϕ] + 
     D[f[θ, ϕ], θ] Cos[θ] Cos[ϕ] - (D[
         f[θ, ϕ], ϕ] Sin[ϕ])/Sin[θ]);
y = Subscript[R, 
    0] (f[θ, ϕ] Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ] + 
     D[f[θ, ϕ], θ] Cos[θ] Sin[ϕ] + (D[
         f[θ, ϕ], ϕ] Cos[ϕ])/Sin[θ]);
z = Subscript[R, 
    0] (f[θ, ϕ] Cos[θ] - 
     D[f[θ, ϕ], θ] Sin[θ]);## Heading ##

    ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

to obtain a figure like below:

[image: this]

Here, I would like to plot only the circumference points (as I need to extract those data) and not shade the whole region. Can someone suggest how to do it using ParametricPlot2D options?

Thanks

Comment: When I run your command, I get a blank plot.  Are there other pieces to your code that you haven't included?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I have included the entire code.

Comment: Now I get a graph that is different from what you plot (it's a sort of rounded hexagon shape).  It looks like you're trying to plot the projection of a 3D shape onto the 2-D plane, is that correct?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert, Yes. use $\epsilon_e=0.0$ u get a sphere. Yes. I need the plot on a 2D XY plane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {θ, 0, 2 π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, 
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5, LightBlue], 
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
 Mesh -> {{{π / 2, Directive[Opacity[1], Red, Thick]}}}]
```

[image]

Use `PlotStyle -> None` to get:

[image]

Comment: Note that this is the intersection with the $xy$-plane, not the projection onto the plane, which is not strictly the same thing.  However, it seems to be what the OP wanted.